# Getting ValueError while implementing LSTM in keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, keras, sentiment-analysis

I am getting this error while implementing LSTM in Keras:

""""Error when checking input: expected lstm_16_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (156060, 1)""""

I have 156060 text phrases all of different lengths, so I was trying to implement LSTM on it without padding. So at first I indexed all these phrases into numerical values and so I got an array of shape (156060,1) and I have labels of shape (156060, 5). 
Now I implemented my model like this:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape = (156060,1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(5, activation= "softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "categorical_crossentropy", 
              metrics = ["accuracy"])
model.summary()

#encoded_docs.shape = (156060,1) and labels.shape = (156060,5)
model.fit(encoded_docs, labels, epochs = 5)
```

I know there is some mistake in my input shape but I am unable to find it.
If someone can explain me this, it will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `input_shape` shouldn't include your `batch_size` dimension. If you want to perform batch optimization, then you should put `input_shape=(1,)` and specify in addition `batch_size=156060` - **but this won't work with LSTM** (or any RNN for that matter). If you're fine with mini-batch optimization, then specify a different size for `batch_size`. You can also set the `batch_size` parameter inside `fit` instead - this will be a little bit more flexible.

LSTM's though will expect a time-dimension. Your input should be of shape: `(156060,time_steps,num_features)` it doesn't make sense that your input is of shape `(156060,1)` if you are trying to train a LSTM. I would learn a bit more about what a LSTM is and what it does before just trying to plug in numbers willy nilly.

Comment: And what will be the time_steps and num_features in this case.

Comment: You have 156060 phrases...if you do word level then `time_steps` would be number of words per phrase and then `num_features` would be the number of features required to describe a word. For a 10 word phrase encoded as one-hot vectors `time_steps` would be 10 and then `num_features` would be the number of words in your dictionary for example.